# android view lifetime / lifecycle

Tags: android, android-view

Could someone please provide explanation or perhaps a link to it ?

Particularly I am interested in lifetime of inflated views, for example with `setContentView`.
I suppose whole view hierarchy becomes eligible for `GC` when activity itself is `GC`'ed, correct ?

How about views dynamically removed with `removeView` ? Are they `GC`'ed or preserved/cached to improve further potential attempts to `inflate` again from same layout ?

Thanks